# What is difference between Map and Set?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) objects are both [iterable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Both store object by `[key, value]` pair.

When to use which? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Here's a great article which explains things well: http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-maps-sets.html

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Provided you are talking about the ES6 types, they aren't the same data structure even though the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) might be implemented with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Your definition of `Map` is right, but a `Set` is a collection of unique values, unlike an array which can have duplicates.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 3];

var set = new Set(array); // Will have [1, 2, 3]
assert(set.size, 3);

var map = new Map();
map.set('a', 1);
map.set('b', 2);
map.set('c', 3);
map.set('C', 3);
map.set('a', 4); // Has: a, 4; b, 2; c: 3, C: 3
assert(map.size, 4);
```

Comment: I think it is worth while to point out explicitly that a Set is not a key-value store.  It is also different from an array in that it has no ordering.

Comment: In Map() , key can be any type [String, number, Object] but in regular object key must be a string type.

Comment: Set is one dimensional unique array, however Map is 2D and has key-value pair, where key shall be unique.

Answer (score 31):

### Summary:

- Use a `Set` when your dataset needs to be composed of unique values
- Use a `Map` when you have **pairs** of associated data. You **map** the keys to the values

### Example `Set`:

There is a meeting with people coming from different organizations. Some people come from the same organization. We need to compose a list all the different organzations. For this we can use a set since we only want to include every organization once:

```js
const organization = new Set();

organization.add('org1');
organization.add('org2');
organization.add('org3');
organization.add('org1');
organization.add('org3');
organization.add('org1');

for(let org of organization){
  console.log(org);
}
```

### Example `Map`:

We have a pack of dogs and want to assign an age to each dog. We want to map the unique name of each dog to the age of the dog:

```js
const dogs = new Map([['fluffy', 10], ['barkie', 13]]);

dogs.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key, value));
```

**How is `Map` different from an `Object`?**

An `Object` is also a collection of key value pairs and can fulfill often the same purpose as a `Map` can (which is creating key-value pairs). However, there are some key differences between a `Map` and an `Object`:

- `Map` is built in Iterable, this allows it to use the `for of` loop or its implementation of the `forEach()` method which an plain JS `Object` cannot use.
- `Map` has some nice built in methods on its `prototype` which makes working with it very nicely. Because al `Objects` inherit from `Object.prototype` is has access to more useful methods. For example, the `size()` method on `Map` returns the number of keys in the `Map`.

Answer (score 19):

```
var obj = {};
obj.name= "Anand Deep Singh";
console.log(obj.name); //logs "Anand Deep Singh"
```

similarly in **ES6**, we can use regular object.

```
var map = new Map();
map.set("name","Anand Deep Singh");
console.log(map.get("name")); //logs "Anand Deep Singh"
```

But noticeable thing is a **Map** isn’t created with the **literal object syntax**, and that one uses **set** and **get** methods to **store** and **access data**.

It has a **has** method to check whether the key exists in the object or not, **delete** method to delete the object and **clear** method to clear the entire object.

**Set** is a unique list of values.  It’s simply a unique list.

```
var set = new Set(["a", "a","e", "b", "c", "b", "b", "b", "d"]);
console.log(set); //logs Set {"a", "e", "b", "c", "d"}
```

A Set can’t be accessed like an array, and it provides the same methods as a Map.

Comment: `Developers usually just use regular JavaScript objects when they want maps.` Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Its all depends upon your requirement and the way you implement solution for the problems. Mostly, I use Array or Object literal, if I want to save any data. I hardly use both that is why its all depend upon you will :)

Comment: I would not advertise "Developers usually just use regular JavaScript objects when they want maps." as a heading to an answer. While it may make sense to use an Object instead of a Map, it is not always the case (as you already pointed out). Such a statement can and will cause new JS devs to adopt wrong habits. Please remove that heading and make your answer more explicit.

Comment: I updated the answer. Although at that time when i wrote this reply it was not much common thing thats why I wrote that. Although thanks for reminding me (:

Answer (score 4):

There are two main data structures:

- Objects:
  are used for storing keyed collections.
- Arrays:
  are used for storing ordered collections.

But that’s not enough for real life. That’s why Map and Set also exist.

- Map:
  is a collection of keyed data items, just like an Object. But the main difference is that Map allows keys of any type.

For instance:

```
let map = new Map();

map.set('1', 'str1');   // a string key
map.set(1, 'num1');     // a numeric key
map.set(true, 'bool1'); // a boolean key


let hamid = { name: "Hamid" };
// hamid is the key for the map
map.set(hamid, 123); // an object key
```

- Set
  : is a special type collection – “set of values” (without keys), where each value may occur only once.

instance:

```
let set = new Set();

let hamid= { name: "Hamid" };
let pete = { name: "Pete" };
let mary = { name: "Mary" };

// visits, some users come multiple times
set.add(hamid);
set.add(pete);
set.add(mary);
set.add(hamid);
set.add(mary);

// set keeps only unique values
alert( set.size ); // 3
```

https://javascript.info/map-set

Answer (score 1):

A set can never have any duplicates, it consists of unique values. No matter how many times you write the same value, the set will only bring one of them. For example:

```
const colorsSet = new Set([
  'orange',
  'orange',
  'purple',
  'pink',
  'pink',
  'pink',
]); 
// here we have 2 oranges, 3 pinks and 1 purple, but since SETS can NOT have duplicates we will get:
// set(3) {'orange', 'purple', 'pink'})

console.log(colorsSet); // this can be proven also by looking at the size of a set

// We can get the size of a set:
console.log(colorsSet.size); // 3

// We can check if a certain element is in a set:
console.log(colorsSet.has('pink')); // If pink is in set, TRUE
console.log(colorsSet.has('white')); // If white is NOT in set, FALSE

// We can add new elements to a set:
colorsSet.add('black');

// We can also delete elements:
colorsSet.delete('purple'); // it must be straight forward names
console.log(colorsSet); // Set(3) {'orange', 'pink', 'black'}

// We can delete all of the elements in the set:
// colorsSet.clear();


//Sets are iterables, so we can loop over them:
for (const color of colorsSet) console.log(color);
```

We can use to map values to keys and we can use any data types we want, but set is basically just a collection of unique values. Maps are more useful than sets in my opinion. You can use them together. For example:

```
const map = new Map(); // we create an empty map
// to fill up the map we can use SETS

map.set('nameOfFriend', 'locationOfFriend');
map.set('Alicia', 'NYC')
console.log(map.set('Alex", "Washington')); // if you call the set method, it will return the map. 

// Map(3) {'nameOfFriend' => 'locationOfFriend', 'Alicia' => 'NYC', 'Alex' => 'Washington'}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have unique values that you want to put in the set, then you should use Set as it is made for unique values
else if you don't have any issues with 2 or more same values then you should prefer Map

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).