# What are the semantic differences between `Set` and a `Map` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It seems that everything you can do with `Set` you can do with `Map`? Is this correct?

What are the semantic differences between a `Set` and a `Map`?

Edit: the linked "dupe" does not enumerate the semantic differences between the two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript Map object vs Set object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085708/javascript-map-object-vs-set-object)

Comment: That answer doesn't enumerate the semantic differences IMO.

Comment: In some languages (ruby, for example), Set type __is implemented__ with a hashmap (where all values are boolean `true` or something)

Comment: A Set is a mathematical Set: a collection of unique entities. Maps do not have that restriction. Nor are Sets 'keyed': you can iterate them in insertion order but cannot give the elements meaningful names (not even integer indicies) in the context of the data structure.

Comment: A set is not the same as a map. A set does not have a key value pair. It's more like an array with unique values.

Comment: So the semantic difference is that the `Set` contains unique items and a `Map` maps unique keys to values. And that is the extent of the difference? It's just that I could trivially implement a `Set` by using just the keys of a `Map`?

Comment: @BenAston nope. A Set, again, is a *mathematical* Set, all the values are unique. Maps (as mentioned in the linked dupe) can have the same value repeatedly: `new Map([['a', 3], [{}, 3], [new Date(), 3]])`.

Comment: I don't get the emphasis on uniqueness (even though I grok that sets are defined by having unique contents) because the keys in a `Map` are also unique, making using a `Map` for a set trivial. And Map keys can also be anything you want (objects etc).

Comment: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) vs [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) ;

Comment: @BenAston because data structures hold *values*. Keys are just a convenient way to access them. Maps and Sets do not offer the same contract, don't have the same algorithmic complexity for operations, etc. The fact that I can implement a Map using arrays does not make Maps irrelevant. There's also the readability angle: if I read your code and see a Set then I *know* that the values are unique, and that the uniqueness *matters*, otherwise you'd have probably used an array.

Comment: Okay thank you. That clarifies and I will accept as an answer.

Comment: Adding objects to Set, does not guarantee uniqueness? As in mySet.add({})

Comment: @VedranMaricevic yes by unique reference. Remember that `{} !== {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have retracted my close vote.

A quick google of 'set vs. hashtable' or 'set vs. hashmap' turns up numerous SO questions, mostly in the Java tag, but I didn't see a single answer that actually tackled the difference in a good conceptual way (although a few linked to relevant resources).

Let's start with what data structures *are*: namely containers for values. The values can be whatever for the most part. Some data structures are homogeneous, some aren't. Some have restrictions (e.g. Map can have arbitrary keys but POJOs can only have string or symbol keys), some don't, some are ordered, some aren't, etc. All of these tradeoffs generally boil down to performance.

A Set is a data structure that holds *unique* values. Let's compare to an array:

```
Array.from(new Set([1,2,2,3])).toString() === [1,2,2,3].toString();
// false
```

Like arrays or lists, Sets in JavaScript are linear: you can traverse them in order*. But unlike arrays (more like lists) Sets are not indexed. You can't say `new Set(1)[0];`.

Maps on the other hand *ahem* *map* keys to values (indexed). If I have a Map `new Map([['a',1]])`, then `.get('a')` will return `1`. Order is not generally considered important for Maps, that what key indexes are for. Nor is uniqueness: `new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 1]])` stores the value 1 twice** and you can access it from either key.

Even if, like me, you are primarily a self-taught programmer, I highly recommend familiarizing yourself with basic data structures as it offers valuable insight into problem identification and general solutions. If you find yourself using `Array.prototype.shift` a lot for instance, you probably wanted a FIFO queue/linked list instead.

---

* Sets in general are *unordered*, the retention of insertion order is a JavaScript thing.

** The underlying implementation may as an optimization store it only once, but that is an implementation detail and opaque to you the user.

Comment: Can you recommend a book or reference on data structures that you found useful?

Comment: Actually although its a little dense [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type#Examples_2) is a decent resource. At least a few of the ADT examples in the link should be reasonably familiar-sounding.